# how to setup cocos2d-x-3.2 correctly

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I double click the `setup.py` and `setup` but skip all step about setup Android environment. Then I run the command `cocos` and running time errors occur.

```
F:\lib\cocos2d-x-3.2\cocos2d-x-3.2\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\/cocos.py 0.7 - coc
os console: A command line tool for cocos2d

Available commands:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\lib\cocos2d-x-3.2\cocos2d-x-3.2\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\/cocos.py",
 line 492, in <module>
    help()
  File "F:\lib\cocos2d-x-3.2\cocos2d-x-3.2\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\/cocos.py",
 line 433, in help
    classes = parse_plugins()
  File "F:\lib\cocos2d-x-3.2\cocos2d-x-3.2\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\/cocos.py",
 line 400, in parse_plugins
    cp = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_no_value'
```

I want to know the correct stop.

Answer (score 0):

Download Cocos2dx Latest version from http://www.cocos2d-x.org/download

iOS Setup
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXqgSNUf9Cc

Android Setup
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LI1IrRp_0w

Answer (score -2):

how to setup cocos2dx
        -> download cocos2dx
        ->download android ndk
        ->download android sdk
        ->download python
        ->download apache ant

now setup cocos2dx
        ->open cmd
        ->cd cocos2dx folder
        ->setup.py
        ->set android ndk path
        ->set android sdk path
        ->set ant path to bin
complete setup

create new project
cocos new MyGame -p com.MyCompany.MyGame -l cpp -d ~/MyCompany